# A better implementation for pattern matching a tree-like option structure

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples, scala-option

```
  def leadParser(optionTuples: Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[(
                                Option[Iterable[EmailLead]],
                                Option[Iterable[QuestionLead]])],
                                Option[Iterable[LocalMarketQuestionLead]])],
                                Option[Iterable[OfferLead]])],
                                Option[Iterable[Bid]])],
                                Option[Iterable[CreditApplicationLeadWithEbayId]])]) = {
    optionTuples match{
      case None => (None, None, None, None, None, None)
      case Some(c) =>
        val creditApplictaionIteratorOption = c._2
        c._1 match {
          case None => (None, None, None, None, None, creditApplictaionIteratorOption)
          case Some(b) =>
            val bidIteratorOption = b._2
            b._1 match {
              case None => (None, None, None, None, bidIteratorOption, creditApplictaionIteratorOption)
              case Some(o) =>
                val offerIteratorOption = o._2
                o._1 match {
                  case None => (None, None, None, offerIteratorOption, bidIteratorOption, creditApplictaionIteratorOption)
                  case Some(l) =>
                    val localMarketQuestionIteratorOption = l._2
                    l._1 match {
                      case None => (None, None, localMarketQuestionIteratorOption, offerIteratorOption, bidIteratorOption, creditApplictaionIteratorOption)
                      case Some(q) =>
                        val questionIteratorOption = q._2
                        val emailIteratorOption = q._1
                        (emailIteratorOption, questionIteratorOption, localMarketQuestionIteratorOption, offerIteratorOption, bidIteratorOption, creditApplictaionIteratorOption)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I know the input Option[... looks insane but this is what I receive from a Spark operation so I have to deal with it. Could there be a better way of getting all the Iterator Options from this complicated tuple/option structure ?

Comment: i am thinking about a recursive function which is much easier to read. have you tried to write a recursive function yet?

Comment: At every iteration the input type changes. I thought of using a flatMap with a function but it did not work. @B.Kemmer 
And within that function I actually tried to define the inputType as 
Option[(Option[Iterator], Option[_])] but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching to declare variables, not just in `case` statements.  This unlocks several non-nesting possibilities that will be more readable.  For example:

```
def leadParser(optionTuples: Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[Iterable[EmailLead]],Option[Iterable[QuestionLead]])],Option[Iterable[LocalMarketQuestionLead]])],Option[Iterable[OfferLead]])],Option[Iterable[Bid]])],Option[Iterable[CreditApplicationLeadWithEbayId]])]) = {
    val (creditRest, credit) = optionTuples.getOrElse(None -> None)
    val (bidRest, bid) = creditRest.getOrElse(None -> None)
    val (offerRest, offer) = bidRest.getOrElse(None -> None)
    val (localRest, local) = offerRest.getOrElse(None -> None)
    val (email, question) = localRest.getOrElse(None -> None)
    (credit, bid, offer, local, email, question)
}
```

Here we've used `getOrElse` on each successively nested `Option` in order to encapsulate the fallback values.

The pattern matching syntax (in both variable declaration and `match` clauses) can be nested to account for internal structure.  That gives you another possibility:

```
def leadParser(optionTuples: Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[(Option[Iterable[EmailLead]],Option[Iterable[QuestionLead]])],Option[Iterable[LocalMarketQuestionLead]])],Option[Iterable[OfferLead]])],Option[Iterable[Bid]])],Option[Iterable[CreditApplicationLeadWithEbayId]])]) = {
    optionTuples match {
        case Some((Some((Some((Some((Some((a, b)), c)), d)), e)), f)) => (a, b, c, d, e, f)
        case Some((Some((Some((Some((None, c)), d)), e)), f)) => (None, None, c, d, e, f)
        case Some((Some((Some((None, d)), e)), f)) => (None, None, None, d, e, f)
        case Some((Some((None, e)), f)) => (None, None, None, None, e, f)
        case Some((None, f)) => (None, None, None, None, None, f)
        case None => (None, None, None, None, None, None)
    }
}
```

Here we use several nested pattern matches to capture the internal structure of the complex value.

The other natural choices here would be some sort of `for` comprehension that prevents nesting, or a generic recursive function that flattens this type of optional tuple.  Finally, if this is too cumbersome, you might consider using a library like Shapeless, might allow you to work with this complex type more concisely.  I think that would be overkill, though.